# ...oracle group by syntax for beginners

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax

**What is the problem in this please?**

```
select inst.id            
,      inst.type          as "TypeOfInstall"
,      count(inst.id)     as "NoOfInstall"
from   dm_bsl_ho.installment inst
group  by inst.type
```

Comment: what is the error shown? and where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do a `GROUP BY` in most RDBMSs, your selection is limited to the following two things:

- Columns mentioned in the `GROUP BY` - in your case, that's `inst.type`
- Aggregate functions - for example, `count(inst.id)`

However, the `inst.id` at the top is neither one of these. You need to remove it for the statement to work:

```
SELECT 
       type       as "TypeOfInstall"
 ,     COUNT(id)  as "NoOfInstall"
 FROM  dm_bsl_ho.installment
 GROUP BY type
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not allowed to use single function with group function. Like mixing `count` with single row function.

You should include the `group by` function:

```
 select inst.type          as "TypeOfInstall"
 ,      count(inst.id)     as "NoOfInstall"
 from   dm_bsl_ho.installment inst
 GROUP BY inst.type;
```